# Validate form using jquery and submit using php from jquery(if form.valid()

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, forms

I want a form which validates using jquery on form submission, and, while giving a jquery notification, it should also submit content to a MySQL db. I have written PHP code for submitting the form data into the database and to validate form using jquery, but it isn't working:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#form").validate({
                rules: {
                    name: "required",
                    email: {
                        required: true,
                        email: true
                    },
                },
                messages: {
                    name: "Please enter your first name",
                    email: "Please enter a valid email address",
                
                }
            });
    });
```

```css
#form .formelement
{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 8px 10px;
    width: 340px;
}

#form .formelement label,textarea {
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    width: 110px;
}

#form .submit {
    padding: 10px;
    width: 220px;
    height: 40px;
}

#form .formelement label.error {
    color: red;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 4px 0 10px 100px;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left;
    width: 220px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8"/ >

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
 <script src="form_valid.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
 
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>

<div class="maincontent">
  <div class="content1">
   <article class="topcontent">
<form action="" id="form" >      
    <center><legend><h1> Enter Your Details </h1></legend>


            <div class="formelement">
                <label for="name">Name: </label>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name"/>
            </div>
 
            <div class="formelement">
                <label for="email">Email-ID: </label>
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
            </div>
   
   <div class="formelement">
       <label for="bio">Your Message: </label>
    <textarea rows="3" cols="60" name="bio" id="bio"></textarea>
   </div>
   
   <div class="formelement">
                <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" class="submit"/>
            </div>


</form>
   </article>
   </div>
 </div>

 </body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="email" name="email" required>
```

would make the  browser check simple stuff in the email and not submit it if it's incorrect format, Where you submitting it to ? Can't see the place it's going. What errors you getting ?

Comment: and required on the name input aswell